# Convert Month Number to Month Name

Tags: shell-script, date, ksh

Is there a way to convert month number to name with a script?

example:

`2013-10-22` will become `Oct 22`

Thanks.

BTW, I don't have the GNU date and my OS is AIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a usable `awk` (or `nawk`):

```
BEGIN {
    nmon=split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",month)
    for(mm=1;mm<=nmon;mm++) {
        month[month[mm]]=mm
        month[sprintf("%02i",mm)]=month[mm]
    }
}

/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]/ {
    split($1,bits,/-/)
    printf("%s %02i\n",month[bits[2]],bits[3])
}
```

The `BEGIN{}` block creates a mapping hash. It's a bit more general purpose than you strictly need (I just happen to have it laying around), its indexes are the short-name, the month ordinal (number) and the two-digit month ordinal with a leading zero. This means you can convert name to number or vice versa. You can easily adapt it for long month names too (and possibly localisation, but let's not get carried away).

The next block looks for lines containing a likely looking date string, splits on "-" and converts the date. (This also works in `gawk`, but if you happen to have that, then `strftime()` and `mktime()` are a more elegant solution.)

A basic `ksh` shell version, since AIX has `ksh`:

```
set -A month pad Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

while IFS=- read yyyy mm dd junk; do
    echo ${month[$mm]}
done
```

This uses an *array* (POSIX `sh` does not have arrays, `bash` does, so you may do something similar with it too). Note that this relies on `ksh` to handle the leading 0 in a month number, it just treats it as an integer. Since `ksh` (and `bash`) arrays are zero based, we stuff a dummy "pad" value into index 0 rather than play with +1/-1 on indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
date +"%B %d"
```

Will display `January 1`

```
date +"%b %d"
```

Will display `Jan 1`